# Gradient colors in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background, gradient

I know that Internet Explorer has some proprietary extensions so that you can do things like create divs with a gradient background.  I can't remember the element name or it's usage.  Does anyone have some examples or links?

Comment: I believe you're looking for [this specific CSS setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997.aspx).

Comment: One little note: I found a little bug when working on IE9. If you don't spell out the entire HEX color it won't work correctly. i.e. #cccccc NOT #ccc Hope this helps.

Comment: Be careful of applying gradients to table rows. IE seems to treat those differently, so to get any of the other solutions to this question to work, you'll need to wrap your tr content in a div and apply the gradient to that.

Comment: In addition to @mdostudio, you can even use #FFFFFFFF (8 characters) where the first two define transparency. Full transparant (FF) to solid color (00).

Comment: @user995849: that is not a bug. The `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient-API` simply doesn't accept shorthand CSS color-values. I wrote a fully referenced explanation here: [Why are 3-digit hex color code values interpreted differently in Internet EXPLORER?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32153998/588079) . That API also has another 'surprise': it's full format (including alpha) is actually `aarrggbb` and NOT `rrggbbaa`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Look at the custom CSS filters IE can handle
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847.aspx

Answer (score 83):

The code I use for all browser gradients:

```css
background: #0A284B;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0A284B), to(#135887));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0A284B, #135887);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0A284B', endColorstr='#135887');
zoom: 1;
```

You will need to specify a height or `zoom: 1` to apply `hasLayout` to the element for this to work in IE.

---

**Update:**

Here is a LESS Mixin (CSS) version for all you LESS users out there:

```css
.gradient(@start, @end) {
    background: mix(@start, @end, 50%);
    filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr="@start~", EndColorStr="@end~")";
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@start), to(@end));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@start, @end);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @start, @end);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(@start, @end);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(@start, @end);
    background: linear-gradient(@start, @end);
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Perfect snippet for gradients. zoom:1 is the key to answering this question though.

Comment: @Blowsie I am having trouble with gradients when used in conjunction with a border radius. In that the background effectively squares off the corners. Obviously dependant on the colour range selected the background fills out the corners. Is there a trick for handling border radius and a background gradient in IE?

Comment: @codepuppy This is a known bug with no solution, large frameworks like bootstrap have opted for the border-radius with no gradient.

Comment: @codepuppy apparently there's a way to use border-radius AND gradients in IE. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7544248/1446845

Answer (score 11):

The `filter` style should work for IE8 and IE9.

```
.gradientClass
{
  filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#e6e6e6', endColorstr='#CCCCCC');       
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A significant gotcha when it comes to gradients in IE is that although you can use Microsoft's filters...

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FCCA6D', endColorstr='#FEFEFE');
zoom:1;
```

...they **kill clear type** on any text covered by the gradient. Given that the purpose of gradients is normally to make the UI look better, that's a show stopper for me.

So for IE I use a repeating background image instead. If the background image css is combined with the gradient CSS for other browsers (as per Blowsie's answer), other browsers will ignore the background image in favour of the gradient css, so it will only end up applying to IE.

```
background-image: url('/Content/Images/button-gradient.png');
```

There are plenty of sites you can use to quickly generate a gradient background; I use [this](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/gradient/).

Answer (score 6):

Great tool from Microsoft, allows you to examine colors real-time and generates CSS for all browsers:
http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/default.html

```css
/* IE10 */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #B7B8BD 300%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #B7B8BD 300%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #B7B8BD 300%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(3, #B7B8BD));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #B7B8BD 300%);

/* Proposed W3C Markup */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #B7B8BD 300%);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just thought I'd add this useful link:  http://css3please.com/

Shows how to get gradients working in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Note that IE10 will support gradients as follows:

```css
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#017ac1, #00bcdf);
```

Answer (score 2):

Right from ScriptFX.com [article](http://www.scriptfx.com/transitions/gradient/gradient_filter.htm):

```
<body bgcolor="#000000" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">

    <div style="width:100%;height:100%; filter: progid:
        DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient (GradientType=1,
        StartColorStr='#FF006600', EndColorStr='#ff456789')">

Your page content goes in here ...... at the end of all the page content, you must close the <div> tag, immediately before the closing <body> tag.... as below

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.red {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e02a42', endColorstr='#a91903', GradientType=0); /* IE6-9 */
    height: 0; /* gain layout IE5+ */   
    zoom: 1; /* gain layout IE7+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I discovered while struggling with IE 9 gradient.

1. The `-ms-filter` did not work for me.  I had to use simply `filter`.
2. I had to add `height: 100%` to my class for IE to use the gradient.

Comment: you might want to check out [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/), which is a script for IE to add support for some CSS features including gradients. It works in IE9 as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I inserted it on header section

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

then in style section insert it

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#49708f', endColorstr='#293f50');
zoom: 1;
```