# Css: -webkit-border-radius for Internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I want to set border for a div,

Using: `-webkit-border-radius` working fine on Chrome but it is not working for Internet explorer, triple versions: ie 6, 7 and 8 :D

Is there any other attribute like `-webkit-border-radius` specifying for IE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get border-radius and gradient backgrounds in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969772/is-there-a-way-to-get-border-radius-and-gradient-backgrounds-in-ie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE has yet to implement the `border-radius` CSS property. I believe with IE9 they will be implementing it. As for alternative options and an explanation from the team themselves, here is a link:

EDIT: [IE9 does supports "border-radius".](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705)

[Rounded Corners in Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250413(VS.85).aspx)

Here is another SO link as well that has more detail:

[Support for “border-radius” in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie)

One more, here is an official MSDN blog posting discussing the topic:

[The CSS Corner: About CSS corners](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/19/the-css-corner-about-css-corners.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

CSS properties that begin with a hyphen are vendor-prefixes:

- -webkit (for Webkit browsers, Chrome and Safari)
- -o (for Opera)
- -moz (for Firefox and, I think, for the Gecko rendering engine)
- -ms (for IE)
- -khtml (for Konqueror)

These prefixes are ignored by the *other* browser engines.

`-webkit-border-radius` is targeted to Webkit's implementation of the `border-radius` property. So far as I know `border-radius` won't be implemented by IE until [IE 9](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/).

Comment: It is pity that Border-radius does not support for Ie 7 and 8. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/). It very easily lets you adapt CSS3 decorators for IE.

I did a [small demo](http://www.coffeepowered.net/projects/sass-mixins.php) of it with Sass a few days ago, if you'd like to check it out in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about you, but I tested `border-radius:15px` in IE9, it works :)