# IE and Chrome jQuery and css support issue

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I developed little site that use:

```
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;

-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

for making shadow and radius on boxes. And `$(".mainpage").show()` Jquery function to show new content qhen user click on some link.

All of this codes work on Firefox normal. But if I use IE , border and radius not works ,and in Chrome calling hidden content not works. 
Should I delete all this codes for making all browser supports or is there any trick for them?

Comment: It might be worth your while having a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647974/css-webkit-border-radius-for-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0):

IE 9+ will support border radius's but until then you'll have to use css tricks for IE

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support CSS for rounded corners, however it does support shadows. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086(VS.85).aspx.

I don't know what you mean with "Chrome calling hidden content not works".

Comment: I have a <div id="mainpage"> </div>  tag. And I made it display:none in .css file.When user click login ,login page disappears  and mainpage tag appears.