# How to use Border Radius CSS on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

How can i use border-radius on all versions of IE?

```
.myclass {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Is it possible with jquery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Css: -webkit-border-radius for Internet explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647974/css-webkit-border-radius-for-internet-explorer)

Comment: are you did any effort for searching the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since border radius (and other CSS3 properties) is not supported in older browsers, you can use [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) for example. Keep in mind that you are referring to styling not to scriping. So asking if it can be done with jQuery is a bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS3 PIE http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have try with the plugin  dd_roundies([download link](http://dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/#download)) for the border radius on IE.
Hopes It may helps you

Comment: it says there are issues with it on ie8 and opera?

Comment: its says "Opera has no support at the moment"

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
DD_roundies.addRule('classname', '8px 8px 8px 8px', true);</script> did u use like this

Comment: I haven't used the plugin. It says on the website link you gave that the plugin doesn't yet support opera and that there are issues with some ie8 versions

Comment: then use the style -webkit-border-radius: 1em; -moz-border-radius: 1em; border-radius: 1em; for opera. I suggested only for the  rounded corner supported in IE

Comment: why waste time using vendor prefixes. just use prefix free

Answer (score 0):

Considering your code you were already in the right place.

[You could find the answer to your problem a bit further down.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909146)