# Are there any way to use border-radius with IE6-9

Tags: internet-explorer-6, border, css

Are there any way to use border-radius with IE6-9 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get border-radius and gradient backgrounds in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969772/is-there-a-way-to-get-border-radius-and-gradient-backgrounds-in-ie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSS Pie](http://css3pie.com/) does a good job at this (and other css3 features) in IE 6-8.

IE9 supports border-radius natively.

Comment: Cool! I've never heard of that before.

Comment: It is very good. but when I put it on my nav, a white color appear on the bottom then disapper after a second ! How can I fix that

Comment: That's a bug with CSS Pie, I believe. Remember, it is beta software, still.

Answer (score 2):

http://css3pie.com/

Is as of yet one of the only ways, also if you are using border radius make sure you declare all 4 sides of the border like so,

```
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
```

As this is how IE9 reads them.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [IE-CSS3](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/) its very effective in working with IE6, IE7 and IE8.