# Can you use rgba colours in gradients produced with Internet Explorer’s filter property?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gradient

Internet Explorer’s `filter` CSS property (`-ms-filter` from IE 8) allows you to do CSS gradients, a bit like the `-webkit-gradient` and `-moz-gradient` properties (see e.g. [question 213750](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213750/gradient-colors-in-internet-explorer)).

However, the syntax doesn’t seem to allow for rgba colours, so you can’t do a gradient from a colour to transparent.

Is there any way to achieve gradients that end in transparency in IE?

Comment: Beware: ie filters cannot handle elements bigger than 4096 pixels high or wide. I found this when making a translucent overlay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop colors can be specified in `#AARRGGBB` notation, where `AA` represents the alpha. For example, `#ffff0000` is fully-opaque red.

This produces a 100% red to 50% black horizontal gradient:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(
    GradientType=1, 
    StartColorStr='#ffff0000', 
    EndColorStr='#80000000'
);
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/WGpC3)

Comment: Aha, I wondered why lots of the `filter` examples used 8-character hex colours. Excellent, cheers.