# IE adds blue border to div where css gradient is used

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm trying to make a gray line, that is fading out to transparent. I created a div, that is 1x100px, and added css gradient to make the fade effect.

It works fine, except in IE where the div gets a blue border, which I cant get rid off.

This is my css for the div

```
#left_header_border {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-1px;
    left:-100px;
    width:100px;
    height:1px;  

    /* gradient */
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, transparent, #cccccc); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, transparent, #cccccc); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,right bottom,color-stop(0, transparent),color-stop(1, #cccccc)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,transparent, #cccccc); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, transparent, #cccccc);
              filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=1, startColorStr='transparent', EndColorStr='#cccccc'); /* IE6–IE9 */
}
```

I've tried to inspect the div, and make it higher, and the gradient seems to work, but the color is blue, and a border is added. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the filter to:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=1, startColorStr='#00cccccc', EndColorStr='#ffcccccc'); /* IE6–IE9 */
```

The filter doesn't allow “transparent” as a color value, but it does allow you to [use an 8-digit hex reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159136/can-you-use-rgba-colours-in-gradients-produced-with-internet-explorers-filter-pr), where the first two digits specify the opacity of the colour (just like the last value in `rgba()` color references).

[More on using RGBA and transparency & using MS Filters](http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/)

if the scary maths bit gets you, you can find e.g. `0.6 transparency` in Windows calculator, open it in scientific view, do **255*0.6 = 153** then click the "hex" checkbox for the conversion  = `99`

in the example above it was starting at the the fully transparent (0.0 opacity) = 255*0 = hex value "`00`" through to fully opaque (1.0 opacity) = 255*1 = hex value "`ff`"

**Update** As kindly linked by *thirtydot* in the comments, here's a handy [converter from RGBa to MS Filter syntax](http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/)

Comment: I was editing to add LOL -  thanks for finding reference Paul!

Comment: @clairesuzy: oops! Sorry, I did leap right in there — please feel free to re-edit back into your own style.

Comment: no need Paul it helped! I just added the calculation info it took me an age to find when I needed it ;)

Comment: @clairesuzy: oh yeah, decimal to hex always hurts my head. Great answer.

Comment: This is useful to generate the `filter` syntax: http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: +1 @thirtydot, brilliant link thanks - now bookmarked, actually is it etiquette for me to update my post with that?

Comment: It's up to you. You upvoted the comment, so it's visible to others without pressing "more comments" which is useful. [I didn't bother to do so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788564/transparency-and-text-problem/4788642#4788642) when someone pointed the same site out to me :)

Comment: ah cool, I'll put it in with credit to you, and I also didn't realise that about the comment flags either, am getting to grips with SO bit by bit.. thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) instead of hard-coding the `filter` style for this sort of thing -- it's a lot easier and more standards-compliant; it allows you to use standard CSS3 for your gradients in older versions of IE.

Comment: Thanks @Spudley, I will check CSS3Pie out :)