# CSS: How can I get this effect gradient in CSS?

Tags: css

[image: effect gradient css]

I'd like to get the gradient effect of purple or white color that starts with a strong tone and gradually this until dimming seems to disappear or become transparent and you see the background behind.It's possible?

I hope I have explained!

Regards!

Comment: google is your friend: css gradients

Comment: [**By far the best I know of**](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543887/gradient-alpha-fade-out-effect-with-css-3

Comment: Since you deleted your question before I could post: http://jsfiddle.net/SBUvQ/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a CSS gradient generator.

Try this one: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

It has a number of presets, some of which look like they might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
   height: 500px;
   width: 300px;
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#8860af, #4e91cc, #c7deee);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#8860af, #4e91cc, #c7deee);
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#8860af, #4e91cc, #c7deee);
}
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/3zt4PRh3)**

Read more **[here](http://www.slideshare.net/LeaVerou/mastering-css3-gradients)**.