# Rounded corners are not rounded in IE

Tags: css3pie, video.js

Any clue?
Tried `pie.htc` but it is not working

```
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-big-play-button {
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  behavior: url(bla bla/PIE.htc);
  position: relative;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is with CSS3pie most likely.

Comment: BTW, it doesn't work either on the official website http://videojs.com/ :-/

Answer (score 0):

It may help to tell the browser that it is expecting IE9+ code like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

(See [Support for "border-radius" in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie))

Comment: Have you tried my solution? I'm currently using it on my site and it works like a charm. There are also multiple other solutions to this on here that just aren't directly linked to video-js. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6130235/728053, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4692686/728053 You could try some of those solutions if you're not a fan of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced problems with CSS3Pie quite a bit.  Read the [Known Issues page](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/) for the full explanations, but the problem I usually have is either with the relative paths or not having the appropriate content-type for .htc in your htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem in link to your ".htc" file. I had same problem and solved it with correct link to PIE.htc (I use PIE.php because this is better for me - this file include PIE.htc and I have not problem with .htaccess file). 
If your rounded corners works in Firefox (for example) and not work IE8 and older then you must have problem in link on PIE file. You must make link to htc file from file where you used rounded corners (not from CSS file but from, for example, home.php).

But without code, test page or something similar is problem to test it and say "you have problem right here".

Comment: if i put the full url (http://localhost..../.../pie.htc), it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Nothing Localhost you are using this on web not only on localhost I think. I describe my situation and tree of files and folders: funkce(folder), css (folder), img (folder), slash_home.php (file) - everything is in same folder with name of project. PIE.php (file - or PIE.htc if you don´t use better ".php") I have inside folder "funkce" and I use PIE in slash_home. Therefor I use "behavior: url(funkce/PIE.php);" because from file slash_home.php I must enter to folder "funkce" and here get file PIE.php.

Comment: "behavior: url(funkce/PIE.php);" is working on localhost and still on web if you have same file tree. With localhost you have only absolute link which works only on localhost but on web is not working.

Comment: well I know localhost would only work on local and not on the web... i'm trying to get it working locally first then i'll try relative paths.

Comment: In my web "behavior: url(funkce/PIE.php);" works in localhost and in web too. On localhost you must have correct link as on web. In FF etc.. PIE works? If yes then you have error in path to PIE file. Try my style of path to PIE file (= from your for example html file ,where you used PIE, to PIE file).

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is an issue with IE 9, gradient backgrounds, and CSS3 borders. In version 3.2.0, at line 329 of the default styles you'll find the reference for `Big Play Button (at start)`. IE 9 is grabbing on to the `filter` declaration.

```
background: #454545;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #454545 0%, #232323 50%, #161616 50%, #3f3f3f 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, color-stop(0%,#454545), color-stop(50%,#232323), color-stop(50%,#161616), color-stop(100%,#3f3f3f));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #454545 0%,#232323 50%,#161616 50%,#3f3f3f 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #454545 0%,#232323 50%,#161616 50%,#3f3f3f 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #454545 0%,#232323 50%,#161616 50%,#3f3f3f 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#454545', endColorstr='#3f3f3f',GradientType=0 );
background: linear-gradient(top, #454545 0%,#232323 50%,#161616 50%,#3f3f3f 100%);
```

If you add an SVG image gradient and use a conditional comment to get rid of the filter you can get rounded borders and a gradient background. Something like [Colorzilla's Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) can help.

CSS:

```
background: #454545; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #454545 0%, #232323 50%, #161616 51%, #3f3f3f 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#454545), color-stop(50%,#232323), color-stop(51%,#161616), color-stop(100%,#3f3f3f)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #454545 0%,#232323 50%,#161616 51%,#3f3f3f 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #454545 0%,#232323 50%,#161616 51%,#3f3f3f 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #454545 0%,#232323 50%,#161616 51%,#3f3f3f 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #454545 0%,#232323 50%,#161616 51%,#3f3f3f 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#454545', endColorstr='#3f3f3f',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

Somewhere in your HTML:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-big-play-button {
    filter: none;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try declaring this in the css file,

overflow:hidden